# MySQL lock row while updating

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

It seems basic what I'm trying to achieve but I can't wrap my head around it.

I, in my database, store inventories of my users built like so;

```
id, userid, item, status

id: identifier of row
userid: unique identifier of user
item: unique identifier of item
status: 0 or 1, where 0 means no longer in the inventory and 1 active
```

Now when an user sells the item on my site, and for example would spam the request, what happens is the item gets sold multiple times, as the row has not been updated yet and in the consecutive requests get approved as well.

Here's a short readable example of my code;

```
function sell(uid, item){
  database.query('SELECT * FROM inventories WHERE user = ' + uid + ', item = ' + item).then((row) => {
    var item = row[0];

    //Check if the item is still in the user is inventory
    if(item.status !== 1){
      console.log('Found item is no longer in the user his inventory, item cannot be sold.');
      return;
    }

    //Remove the item form the inventory
    database.query('UPDATE inventories SET status = 0 WHERE item = ' + item);
  }).catch((err) => { console.log(err); })
}
```

I would like it so the row of the item can no longer be written to while this code is executing, that way no one could sell an item twice, I would assume this is a common thing to do, though I'm not really sure how to achieve this result.

Comment: You could lock the row: `` `SELECT * FROM inventories WHERE user =${uid} AND  item = ${item} FOR UPDATE;` ``.

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina does `FOR UPDATE;` lock a row? what about unlocking it again after the query has successfully executed?

Comment: Yes, I believe it has to be done in a transaction, and to unlock it, just commit.

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina I would have to disable autocommit for my entire project, would I not, I run a lot of queries that autocommit.

Comment: you could always toggle it on and off, surrounding the queries. ie: `SET autocommit = 0;` before  AND `SET autocommit = 1;` after

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina Wouldn't this set it off globally meaning other queries that get executed at the exact same thing will no longer autocommit?